# Why would \u0000 (null characters) end up in an HTTP response

Tags: node.js, curl, unicode, http-headers

I'm using cURL (or Node `request`) and see `\u0000` scattered throughout the response and don't understand why they appear.

---

I figured out I can remove them with `response.body.replace(/\u0000/g, '')` but would like to understand the source of it to see if there's maybe a better way.

I've played around with request headers but don't understand where these characters come from.

Furthermore, when I browse the site in my browser, I don't see them, and copying the request (chrome's Copy as cURL option) into a terminal I do see them.

Is there some request header or some other way I should be removing/detecting these unicode characters?

**Example request headers using Node `request`:**

```
{ 'Content-Type': '*/*; charset=utf-8',
   accept: 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8' 
}
```

**Example cURL** (and my `~/.curlrc` is empty):

```
curl 'http://example.com' -H 'Pragma: no-cache' -H 'DNT: 1' \
   -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,la;q=0.6' \
   -H 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1' \
   -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36' \
   -H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8' \
   -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' --compressed
```

**The response headers:**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Sat, 04 Nov 2017 14:50:13 GMT
Content-Type: text/plain
Last-Modified: Thu, 02 Nov 2017 19:02:13 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: close
ETag: W/"59fc6be1-41e2"
Content-Encoding: gzip
```

Comment: Can you give the link to that site, or is it your local/dev site?

Comment: The `Content-Type` is `text/plain` without charset. In this case, response body containing null character is not invalid. (ISO-8859-1 used to be the default for text media types, but now charset is just unknown when it's not present)

Comment: @randomir unfortunately no, it's not public.

Comment: @cshu does that mean that only way to remove them is after it's been downloaded? Or is there some request header I can include to remove them instead?